# What does the Win32_AllocatedResource function do?

Tags: windows, wmi

I have some difficulties in understanding a function `Win32_AllocatedResource()` and its fields `antecedent and dependent`, can somebody please explain what does this function do, thanks in advance

P.S. please do not copy from MSDN; I read this article but it is very user-unfriendly

Comment: Download this, run Win32_PNPAllocatedResource and it will become clear: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Win32_AllocatedResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394066) WMI class is an association class. Many WMI classes can participate in an association (relationship ), An association is an instance of an association class that relates two other instances by referring to them in its properties. Each instance of an association class `represents a relationship between two specific WMI objects.` The properties of an association class may include pointers, or references, to the two classes or instances.

In this specific case, this class shows the relation between the system resources (Like IRQ and memory address) and Logical devices (like IDE, USB and Video controllers). These kind of classes is for be used in WQL sentence which includes the `ASSOCIATORS OF` keyword.